# Print adresses with printf %016x vs %p on 64bit systems

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I have some trouble with a book that I am currently reading about C and assembly. The author uses a 32 bit environment while I am using 64-bit.
The problem is that the author often uses

```
printf("%08x", &var);
```

To print addresses which works fine on 32 bit. But when I run this on 64-bit I get only half of the address while `%p` gives me the whole address... So why is this so? I of course use `%016x`instead of `%08x`.

The author only uses `%p` for pointers.
So when should I use what?

Comment: `%p` should be right one in both cases; and `&var` is a pointer.

Comment: It's not clear if they often use "%8x" or "%p" anyway the right one for pointers is **always** "%p".

Comment: what I like to do when dealing with printing a lot of pointers is: `printf("0x%" PRIxPTR", (uintptr_t)(&var))` you get `PRIxPTR` and `uintptr_t` from `inttypes.h` I like this approach, because the semantics of printing an integer is pretty clear to me, while the semantics of printing a pointer is kind of foggy. Also, `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to be able to hold the integer representation of a pointer, so it's portable and semantically correct - everyone wins :)

Answer (score 7):

To print pointers in `printf`, using `%p` with `void *` type is the way according to the C standard.

```
printf("%p", (void *)&var);
```